# Working with someone I terminated at a previous company

Tags: human-resources, termination

I recently started a new job at company X and found out that a person I terminated at company Y is working there. They have since become a manager which means we are equals on the company org chart. I fired this person from company X for insubordination and don't want to work with them at company Y. How should I approach this situation when I discuss it with HR?

Comment: how long is this ago?
could the person have changed?

Comment: Two years ago. I don't think they've changed and am worried they'll refuse to follow my orders like before.

Comment: If you're equals on the org chart, they won't have to follow your "orders" will they?

Comment: At the risk of being presumptuous, this doesn't sound like a clean conscience.

Comment: @Joe I would like them to terminate this individual. If they wouldn't do what I say maybe they won't do what they're told here.

Comment: You want the company to fire him just because you (a new employee) think another employee _might_ not do what they are told, even though the company has proof of this employee doing well?  You don't fire people on something that has not happened yet, you honestly just seem power hungry

Comment: "How should I approach this situation when I discuss it with HR?" - Don't discuss it with HR? How is their past relevant to your current position? If you are equals, I would not expect them to "follow your orders", because **you are not their supervisor** and are equals.

Comment: How does that person treat you at the new company ? Is he being professional to you and does not hold any grudge against you ? If he ignores the past, and only focuses on getting the jobs done, then so should you. I would say you should focus on the work at the new company for now. As others said, you are not his boss now.

Answer (score 26):

> How should I approach this situation when I discuss it with HR?

You don't.

Going to HR, your manager, or anyone else to complain about having to work with a former employee will just make you look bad.  Let things play out and if after working with this coworker there is a legitimate reason unrelated to your history for why you should no longer be working with this coworker you bring it up to your manager or whomever assigned you two to work together and let them handle it.  Even then, do not bring up your history as it is irrelevant to both of your current positions.

Also, you mentioned:

> I don't think they've changed and am worried they'll refuse to follow my orders like before.

This type of mentality will not get you very far in this or any other company.  Never mind the fact that you stated that you are *equals* at this new company, so there are no "orders" for you to give them or for them to follow from you.

Answer (score 13):

Insubordination means he didn't follow your orders. We don't know if these were good orders or stupid orders, but you know and he knows. He was fired because you were in a position of power at the time, which you are not now. Which one should have been fired, only you two know. And he has made a good impression at that company, as his promotion shows, which you haven't done (yet).

If you go to HR with basically nothing, they won't fire someone on your say-so. They will do nothing but mark you as a trouble maker, someone with an axe to grind, who might try to get rid of a colleague, so that will be taken into account on further complaints. Or they ask him, and his story will be that he saved Y from tremendous damage and got fired for it.

I'd be very careful in your situation. If you don't want to work with that person, there's a very obvious solution for that.

Answer (score 11):

Don't bring your baggage to a new job. It's best to concentrate on building your own image rather than bringing negative attention to yourself or anyone else when you're new.

I suggest you ignore whatever happened in the past unless it's brought up and you cannot avoid it.

Answer (score 5):

> How should I approach this situation when I discuss it with HR?

You shouldn't discuss this with HR now.

You are new, and apparently your coworker is not. Perhaps this coworker was even promoted in this new company, that part isn't clear. If so, it indicates the company likes them. And there has been no insubordination at this company.

Going to HR and saying "I don't want to work with them." will reflect poorly on you.

Instead, start with a fresh approach. Deal with it if, and only if, something happens that needs outside attention.

Answer (score 5):

Terminating someone does not mean they are a bad person. It just means that they are not the right person for this particular job at this particular company. When they didn't fit in with your old workplace but do fit in with the new one, then that can mean one of two things:

- They changed.
- The culture at the new workplace is different, and their personality is more compatible with it than it was with your old workplace culture.

When their behavior did not change, and that same behavior does not get them fired but makes them thrive in this new environment, then that can only mean that something about this work environment is different. Either it does not give them a reason to behave in an "insubordinate" manner. Or whatever behavior was considered "insubordination" at your old workplace is considered "showing initiative and engagement" at your new workplace.

Anyway, learning why they didn't fit in in your old workplace and why they do fit in with this new one could teach you a lot of valuable information about them and about this new work environment. And if their prior insubordination was directed at you specifically, then maybe also about your own leadership style.

Answer (score 1):

Why HR, unless you have reason to think this person has done something wrong? If you have evidence they lied to get the job. They saw you in the hall and threatened revenge etc.

This sounds like something you might talk to whoever assigns projects about. You could request not to be assigned to the same project as this person. However this might reflect badly more badly on you than them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should quit and look for another job.

1. You obviously have a major problem with this individual. You fired them 2 years ago and you still have an axe to grind with them.

   - As seen with the fact that you want to cause cause them problems.
2. 2 years ago they were lower on the totem pole then you. Now they are your equal so they are clearly growing and developing as a person, at a company that is better than your last job (why else are you now there) you on the otherhand...
3. It seems likely that you fear that they will retalitate against you in some way that will hamper your growth/psosition in this new job.(Why else are you so concerned about something that is clearly NYFB? They don't work for you, if they are insubordinate it is someone else's problem)

---

That being said, if quitting doesn't sound like a good idea, I recommend you talk to HR its the only other way to insure that you won't have to work/interact with them in the near future. Make sure you layout all of your problems with Bob. The sooner you do this, the better. (for them, this obviously won't help you at all).

---

Alternately you can grow the *** up and be an adult. If you remember that they have probably changed a lot over these past 2 years.